# How to display data from mongodb in frontend using expressjs without knowing feilds name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to display data from mongodb in frontend using express js without knowing feilds name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the raw data, you can simply assign the returned data to a string and display that.

Otherwise, you can delimit the data with a colon ( : ), and map the delimited data to objects or variables as you see fit.

You can then return the mapped data via your API.

Comment: @Anu pretty difficult to do for your specific use case as I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Try editing and adding a code snippet or provide some better context.

Answer (score 0):

In your express handler use a code like this:

```
res.render('index', { dump: JSON.stringify(your_db_object)});
```

And in your view show the dump data with a pre tag:

```
<pre>{{dump}}</pre>
```